# Check if ConfigurationProperty value is not set

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, system.configuration

Let's say I have a ConfigurationProperty defined this way:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("TheProp")]
public double TheProp
{
    get{//some code}
    set{//some code}
}
```

How do I check if this ConfigurationProperty has a value or not? DefaultValue will not work in this case, because any double value is a valid value for the configuration property.

Comment: Have you tried using `double?` (`Nullable<double>`) so that the property could have a `null` default value.

Comment: @MikeofSST Very interesting. Is this even possible?

Comment: Is there any problem by checking (TheProp != 0.0)

Comment: @VimalCK Yes. How do I know its not what the user stored?

Comment: @MikeofSST Yeah, I've just checked, looks like it will work. Please add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @TimurNuriyasov I don't know, that's why I didn't put it as an answer.  With my XML configuration properties, I tend to leave the public type as `String` as much as possible and parse the strings into their internal representation in private, rather than letting the XML reader do it.

Comment: @MikeofSST Well, maybe I'll have to use String too.. It just doesn't seem elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making the `type` of the property 'Nullable':

```
[ConfigurationProperty("TheProp")]
public double? TheProp
{
    get{//some code}
    set{//some code}
}
```

This will allow you to test for `if(TheProp.HasValue)`.

Comment: Please note that while this did point me in the right direction, Nullable<double> is not correctly saved into the XML configuration by default. I had to create my own Configuration Element with bool HasValue and double Value

Answer (score 0):

ElementInformation has a property "IsModified" which you can use to find out if configuration property has been assigned a value like this:

```
ConfigurationElement instance = //your configuration property
if (instance.ElementInformation.Properties["propertyname"].IsModified)
{
//property has been assigned a value
}
```

or you can loop through PropertyInformationCollection.